# Class view in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I see that I would benefit from using the class view in visual studio. 
It would give me better overview over my classes, their methods and make it easier for me to see where and when to refactor my class. I assume that it would give me a better structure and enhance the readability of my code.

But....

I find it to awkward to use. I tried to get use it instead of solution explorer, It basically stranded before beginning. I find no similar functionality like "Track Active item in solution explorer".

Any idea on getting started on using the class view or that I just should forget it and stick to solution explorer and stay ignorant? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago some people were sure that writing code will no longer exists and everything is going to be UML modeling, so I guess they were wrong.. its great power is initial model(as it name tells). Personally I found it slow clicking with the mouse and prefer writing my classes with coding..

**The most important thing is to be productive.** My advice is to try it (it helps in design), but if you don't feel comfortable with it, don't worry, a lof of good programmers don't know that it even exists :)